# How can I store more than item in DB using Item Pipeline for Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy, pipeline

I am new in Scrapy framework

I want to store some items in DB using Item Pipeline

**Spider.py**

```
class ExampleSpider(Spider):
    name = "Spider1"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.example.com.com/.../rss_1.xml"]
    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        Examples = sel.xpath('//item')
        items = []
        for Example in Examples:
            item = ExampleItem()
            item['link'] = Example.xpath('.//link/text()').extract()
            item['title'] = Example.xpath('.//title/text()').extract()
            links = item['link']
            titles = item['title']
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

**pipelines.py**

```
class MySQLStorePipeline(object):

    def __init__(self, dbpool):
        self.dbpool = dbpool

    @classmethod
    def from_settings(cls, settings):
        dbargs = dict(
            host=settings['MYSQL_HOST'],
            db=settings['MYSQL_DBNAME'],
            user=settings['MYSQL_USER'],
            passwd=settings['MYSQL_PASSWD'],
            charset='utf8',
            use_unicode=True,
        )
        dbpool = adbapi.ConnectionPool('MySQLdb', **dbargs)
        return cls(dbpool)

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        # run db query in the thread pool
        query = self.dbpool.runInteraction(self._conditional_insert, item, spider)
        query.addErrback(self._handle_error, item, spider)
        # at the end return the item in case of success or failure
        query.addBoth(lambda _: item)
        # return the deferred instead the item. This makes the engine to
        # process next item (according to CONCURRENT_ITEMS setting) after this
        # operation (deferred) has finished.
        return query

    def _conditional_insert(self, tx, item, spider):

        tx.execute("select * from AnnonceGratuit where link = %s", (item['link']))
        result = tx.fetchone()
        if result:
            log.msg("Item already stored in db: %s" % item, level=log.DEBUG)
        else:
            tx.execute("""
                INSERT INTO AnnonceGratuit (link, title)
                VALUES (%s, %s)
            """, (item['link'], item['title'])
            )
            log.msg("Item stored in db: %s" % item, level=log.DEBUG)

    def _handle_error(self, failure, item, spider):
        """Handle occurred on db interaction."""
        # do nothing, just log
        log.err(failure)
```

I success to scrap link and title item

But when i tray to store them ... I have this error

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \')
```

**NB**

When i use the same code with one item, It works and it stored in DB 
But for two item or more it doesn't work !!!

Thank for your help in advance.

Comment: What happens to your SQL code if a null value is returned from `[item['link']` or `[item['title']`?

Comment: when i use one item, I have a result in my DB

Comment: But when i use two items or more, all the column in my table was null

Comment: If you disable your pipeline and output your scrape to JSON, what does your output look like? You see discreet items?

Comment: According to my spider, when i output my scrape to JSON/XML, it works perfect

Comment: Okay so no issue with your items, so where does the failure occur? When running the `select` statement or the `insert`?

Comment: the problem was in the insert

Comment: Can you print out the insert statement before it is executed, and then try running the same statement in MySQL to see if it's possible to get a more detailed error message?

Comment: this is the error -----  _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'), ("\'Vente Maisons \\xc3\\xa0 La Marsa - 650000 Dinars\'",))\' at line 2')
 
2014-04-17 10:11:07+0100 [FluxAnnonce] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.tunisie-annonce.com/upload/flux/rss_1.xml>
 {'link': [u'http://www.tunisie-annonce.com/DetailsAnnonceImmobilier.asp?cod_ann=1464866'],
  'title': [u'Vente Maisons \xe0 La Marsa - 650000 Dinars']}

Comment: I think because my system Ubuntu was in English and I want to scrap frech item with their specific character like "é" ... bacause the error in using character "\"  ... please help

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should check if your item['link'] or item['title'] is a list or a string.
I had same error because I try to store a list into mysql , and after convert the list to string, works fine.